# ASP.NET-Google Single Sign On

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I've been checking the DotNetOpenAuth library samples to see how I can allow users on a Web app to sign in using their Gmail account.

The samples are completely documentation-less especially to someone new to this topic.

Where can I find documentation on the process of using DotNEtOpenAuth for SSO with Google?

Appreciate your help!
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do have a page with "Code Snippets" and links to relevant sections in the documentation, but largely I agree with you in that it's not helpful for someone new to the topic:

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/openid-relying-party-using-asp-net-controls/

Comment: I should add that it really makes no difference if the user is using gmail, yahoo, openid or whatever other provider as it should work the same for all...that's part of its design

Comment: Hi David, I'm still new to this. I figured out that yahoo and google accounts are both openId enabled. True?

Comment: Correct. Openid.net is a great site for more information on openid generally. And this page lists some well known providers...http://openid.net/get-an-openid/

Comment: Hello David, I'm using the OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms sample application. When the login page opens, Im pasting "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" and click on Login. It is always telling me "Failed". Anything to add to make it work with Google?

Comment: have you tried putting the full url: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id -- Sorry, I now see that the SO comments is hiding the first part...

Comment: I ran up the sample and it worked no problems for me. Firstly though, I did have to set the web.config to use the proxy details that my machine has...<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"> 
            <proxy autoDetect="True" usesystemdefault="True"/> 
        </defaultProxy>

Comment: I did without luck. Anyways, I just integrated ASP.NET Web Forms with DotNEtOpenAuth - connecting to Gmail. Ill post about it to help others having same questions/problems. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi David, I guess its a proxy issue! yesterday I made it work without proxy,today testing with proxy resulting in this exception "Sequence contains no elements" I did configure the proxy as you said still ame problem! ill research it more. thanks

Comment: Link in this answer is dead now